# Accessing web services

Tags: python, web-services, suds

I know there are many similar questions-solutions like this but none of solution working for me.

I am trying to access web service but getting HTTP Error : 401 unauthorized.

Here is my code :

```
from suds.transport.http import HttpAuthenticated
from suds.client import Client
import base64
url = 'http://server.something.com/path/to/Service.svc'

transport = HttpAuthenticated()
client = Client(url,username='******', password='********')
```

And getting below error :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./getDetails.py", line 127, in <module>
test()
File "./getDetails.py", line 121, in test
client = Client(url,username='****', password='******')
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-               py2.7.egg/suds/client.py", line 109, in __init__
self.wsdl = Definitions(url, options)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7- py2.7.egg/suds/wsdl.py", line 172, in __init__
root = p.parse(url=url).root()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/sax/parser.py", line 133, in parse
fp = self.transport.open(Request(url))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/https.py", line 69, in open
return  HttpTransport.open(self, request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/suds-0.3.7-py2.7.egg/suds/transport/http.py", line 72, in open
raise TransportError(str(e), e.code, e.fp)
suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: Unauthorized
```

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi there!, I think you need to set your username and password as headers. Does your service exposes any authentication method? or have any authentication object?

Comment: Sorry I didn't get you.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this resolve you question but I recommend you to use this library [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)

Example

```
import requests
response = requests.get('https://api.github.com/user', auth=('user', 'pass'))
```

According with you code you pointing to a root service not to a method.

Comment: How do I call method after this?? In my code i was first trying to initialize client. and using that I can call method.

Comment: sorry I miss read you code and miss you service is soap base right?